# Find a smooth atlas for the manifold $M=\left\{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4\ | \ x^4+y^4+zt=1\right\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have this exercise:

> Let $M=\left\{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4\ | \ x^4+y^4+zt=1\right\}$
>
> 1. Prove that M is a smooth manifold and find the dimension
> 2. Explicitly build a smooth atlas (it's not necessary to check the $\mathscr{C}^\infty$-compatibility beetween the charts)

For the first point I have proved that $M$ is a smooth manifolds with $\dim{M}=3$ using the theorem about the fiber of an element on a differential function beetween manifolds.
But for the second point I have no idea about what to do. Generally I have  a vague geometric interpretation of the manifold that permits me to try to build some atlases, but this time I can't. So, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Solve the defining equation for, e.g., $t$, as function of the other variables, so that $M$ is a graph of that function.